# Is there an alternative to joinWithCassandraTable for DataFrames in Spark (Scala) when retrieving data from only certain Cassandra partitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

When extracting small number of partitions from large C* table using RDDs, we can use this:

```
val rdd = …  // rdd including partition data
val data = rdd.repartitionByCassandraReplica(keyspace, tableName)
    .joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, tableName)
```

Do we have available an equally effective approach using DataFrames?

**Update (Apr 26, 2017):**

To be more concrete, I prepared an example.

I have 2 tables in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE ids (
   id text,
   registered timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE cpu_utils (
   id text,
   date text,
   time timestamp,
   cpu_util int,
   PRIMARY KEY (( id, date ), time)
)
```

The first one contains a list of valid IDs and the second one cpu utilization data. I would like to efficiently get average cpu utilization per each *id* in table *ids* for one day, say "2017-04-25".

The most efficient way with the RDDs that I know of is the following:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val date = "2017-04-25"
val partitions = sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, "ids")
  .select("id").map(r => (r.getString("id"), date))

val data = partitions.repartitionByCassandraReplica(keyspace, "cpu_utils")
  .joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, "cpu_utils")
  .select("id", "cpu_util").values
  .map(r => (r.getString("id"), (r.getDouble("cpu_util"), 1)))

// aggrData in form: (id, (avg(cpu_util), count))
// example row: ("718be4d5-11ad-4849-8aab-aa563c9c290e",(6,723))
val aggrData = data.reduceByKey((a, b) => (
  1d * (a._1 * a._2 + b._1 * b._2) / (a._2 + b._2), 
  a._2 + b._2))

aggrData.foreach(println)
```

This approach takes about 5 seconds to complete (setup with Spark on my local machine, Cassandra on some remote server). Using it, I am performing operations on less than 1% of partitions in table cpu_utils .

With the Dataframes this is the approach I am using currently:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val date = "2017-04-25"

val partitions = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "ids", "keyspace" -> keyspace)).load()
  .select($"id").withColumn("date", lit(date))

val data: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "cpu_utils", "keyspace" -> keyspace)).load()
  .select($"id", $"cpu_util", $"date")

val dataFinal = partitions.join(data, partitions.col("id").equalTo(data.col("id")) and partitions.col("date").equalTo(data.col("date")))
  .select(data.col("id"), data.col("cpu_util"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(avg("cpu_util"), count("cpu_util"))

dataFinal.show()
```

However, this approach seems to load the whole table cpu_utils into memory as execution time here is considerably longer (almost 1 minute).

I am asking if there exists a better approach using Dataframes that would at least reach if not perform better than the RDD approach mentioned above?

P.s.: I am using Spark 1.6.1.

Comment: I have the exact same question & similar code. Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up using RDD approach only throughout my codebase. I realised that everything that can be done with Dataframes, can also be done with RDDs.

Comment: I did come over a blog post by Russell Spitzer (datastax dev) that says DSE 6.0 DataFrame join now does the same thing as the RDD JoinWithCassandra table code.  
Seems to work most of the time which is good because they want to stop support for RDDs in future spark versions.  

http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/