# Scala joinWithCassandraTable result (or CassandraTableScanRDD) to Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using the Datastax `spark-cassandra-connector` to access some data in Cassandra.

To be able to efficiently access all the data I need to my query, I have to use the `joinWithCassandraTable` method to get data from a bunch of partitions back.  This gives me an object of class `com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD` (or similar, to test I'm actually just using the standard `sc.cassandraTable(ks, tbl)` method to read data).

The problem is, all the methods I need to use on the resulting object need an object of class `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`.

I have done a lot of searching around and haven't been able to find anything to help - the closest I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552506/is-there-an-alternative-to-joinwithcassandratable-for-dataframes-in-spark-scala/43552901#comment79863150_43552901) similar question, which I don't think has been sufficiently answered, as it ignores the use case where the recommended method of accessing all the necessary data is to use `joinWithCassandraTable`.

I'm also new to java and scala, so sorry if I'm a little slow.  Any help would be massively appreciated as I'm pretty stuck at this point.

Thanks,
Akhil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is read your RDD into an RDD[Row] and then change that into a DataFrame. Our only issue is we also need the Schema. So lets do this in two steps.

First lets get the schema programmatically from our join target

```
val schema = spark.read.cassandraFormat("dogabase", "test").load.schema

/**
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = 
StructType(StructField(owner,StringType,true), 
StructField(dog_id,IntegerType,true), 
StructField(dog_age,IntegerType,true), 
StructField(dog_name,StringType,true))
**/
```

Then we can make `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` objects out of our Cassandra Driver
rows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val joinResult = 
  sc.parallelize(Seq(Tuple1("Russ")))
    .joinWithCassandraTable("test", "dogabase")
    .map{ case(_, cassandraRow) => Row(cassandraRow.columnValues:_*)} //Unpack our Cassandra row values into a spark.sql.Row
```

Now that we have a schema and an RDD[Row] we can use the createDataFrame method of the spark session

```
val dataset = spark.createDataFrame(joinResult, schema)
dataset.show

/**
+-----+------+-------+--------+
|owner|dog_id|dog_age|dog_name|
+-----+------+-------+--------+
| Russ|     1|     10|    cara|
| Russ|     2|     11|sundance|
+-----+------+-------+--------+
**/
```

And just incase you don't believe me that a DataFrame is a Dataset

```
dataset.getClass
Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
```

## EDIT: Possible needed converters

Some Cassandra types are not valid basis for Spark Rows so you may need to convert them. This could be done by writing a quick conversion function. Unfortunately the built in conversion that the SCC uses makes an internal representation so we can't use those conversions.

```
def convertToSpark(element:Any): Any = {
  case time: org.joda.time.LocalDate => time.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate //Convert to java.util.Date
  case other => other
}
```

Then when making your rows

```
cassandraRow.columnValues.map(convertToSpark):_*
```

Comment: This is fantastic and also solves a bunch of other problems I've been having... Thank you so much! I'll be implementing this tomorrow and will let you know how I get on :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again - this seems to be really close to working, except one of my Cassandra fields is a date and I'm seeing the exception `Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.joda.time.LocalDate is not a valid external type for schema of date`.  Do'u know if this has an obvious fix I'm missing?  Thanks again

Comment: Oh Spark :) The issue is the type returned by the cassandra driver "joda's localdate" is not compatible with Spark. So what you'll need to do is convert those LocalDate's to a spark compatible type. I would suggest you use the Connector built in conversions but those aim at an internal representation and are also not allowed for external sources. I'll put a code example of converting types in answer above.